# How to remove cursor from text field on click of button?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I am trying to do a simple task:

I have an editable text field, two buttons (titles: make editable/ make un-editable) over a window. Idea is: when user clicks "make editable" button, text field should become editable and when he/she clicks "make un-editable", it should become un-editable.

In action of "make un-editable" I am doing this:

```
[myTextField setSelectable:NO];
[myTextField setEditable:NO];
```

and in action of "make editable" I am doing this:

```
[myTextField setSelectable:YES];
[myTextField setEditable:YES];
```

Problem is:

It works fine when myTextField does not have cursor within it or it has cursor but user does not type anything in it and clicks - "make un-editable", then myTextField becomes un-editable but when it has cursor and user clicks "make un-editable" after typing something within it he/she can still edit myTextField.

For its solution I tried to remove cursor from myTextField as soon as user clicks "make un-editable" button, by adding these lines before selectable and editable statements:

1. `[someOtherTextField selectText:self];`
2. `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
            performSelector:@selector(selectText:)
            someOtherTextField
            argument:self
            order:9999
            modes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSDefaultRunLoopMode]];`
3. `[someOtherTextField becomeFirstResponder];`

but none is working for me :(

Can anyone suggest some solution for it?

Comment: someOtherTextField is hidden in this case!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs for `becomeFirstResponder` say

> Use the NSWindow makeFirstResponder: method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly.

I'm not sure if a hidden text field can become first responder, so try:

`[[myTextField window] makeFirstResponder: nil]`

Answer (score 0):

in swift 5

use bellow code

```
 password.window?.makeFirstResponder(nil)
```